# Animated profile pictures on HNQ

Tags: bug, hot-questions, profile-picture

It seems that animated user profile pictures will animate on the HNQ:

> [image: Animated HNQ]

Is this a bug?

Comment: worth noting that it's an external url to an avatar supplied via google account login, it's not the standard experience offered by a native profile avatar

Comment: Google recently changed their API so that resizing uses a different scheme and there doesn't appear to be any way for us to prohibit animated images anymore. If we're really against it, ditching Google images altogether may be the only option. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @animuson I mean I'm never against ditching google ;) but for real, thanks for taking the time to look into this and respond. I'll consider the "bug" reported.